# Angular4 Enable Production Mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli

`ng build --env=prod` is always picking `environment.ts` instead of `environment.prod.ts`is this a bug?

I guess its because **main.ts** imports `environment.ts` by default

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

**main.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/home/app.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  console.log(environment);
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiURL : '/offer-screener-web/'
};
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiURL : '/offer-screener-web/'
};
```

**.angular-cli**

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "qa": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

**ng -v**

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
node: 8.5.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
@angular/common: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler: 4.4.4
@angular/core: 4.4.4
@angular/forms: 4.4.4
@angular/http: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.4
@angular/router: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
typescript: 2.1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `envName` in the environment Object for all the environments , something like this

```
export const environment = {  
  production: true,
  apiURL : '/offer-screener-web/'
  envName: 'prod'
};
```

Comment: This dint work either, here is the issue in github  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7920